# EDITED Learning data not correctly

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning

I'm studying deep-learning.

I'm making figure classifier: circle, rectangle, triangle, pentagon, star. And one-hot-encoded into `label2idx = dict(rectangle=0, circle=1, pentagon=2, star=3, triangle=4)`

But every learning rates per epoch are same and it do not learn about the image.

I made a Layer with using Relu function for activation function, Affine for each layer, Softmax for the last layer, and using Adam to optimizing the gradients.

I have totally 234 RGB images to learn, which has created on window paint 2D tool and it is 128 * 128 size but not using the whole canvas to draw the figure.

And the picture looks like:
[image: Rectangle]
[image: Triangle]
[image: Circle]

The train result. left [] is predict, and the right [] is answer lable(I picked random images to print predict value and answer lable).:

```
epoch:  0.49572649572649574
[ 0.3149641  -0.01454905 -0.23183    -0.2493432   0.11655246] [0 0 0 0 1]
epoch:  0.6837606837606838
[ 1.67341673  0.27887525 -1.09800398 -1.12649948 -0.39533065] [1 0 0 0 0]
epoch:  0.7094017094017094
[ 0.93106499  1.49599772 -0.98549052 -1.20471573 -0.24997779] [0 1 0 0 0]
epoch:  0.7905982905982906
[ 0.48447043 -0.05460748 -0.23526179 -0.22869489  0.05468969] [1 0 0 0 0]

...
epoch:  0.9230769230769231
[14.13835867  0.32432293 -5.01623202 -6.62469261 -3.21594355] [1 0 0 0 0]
epoch:  0.9529914529914529
[ 1.61248239 -0.47768294 -0.41580036 -0.71899219 -0.0901478 ] [1 0 0 0 0]
epoch:  0.9572649572649573
[ 5.93142154 -1.16719891 -1.3656573  -2.19785097 -1.31258801] [1 0 0 0 0]
epoch:  0.9700854700854701
[ 7.42198941 -0.85870225 -2.12027192 -2.81081263 -1.83810873] [1 0 0 0 0]
```

I think the more it learn, prediction should like `[ 0.00143 0.09357 0.352 0.3 0.253 ] [ 1 0 0 0 0 ]`, which means answer index should be close to 0, but it does not. 
Even the train accuracy sometimes goes to 1.0 ( 100% ).

I'm loading and normalizing the images with below codes.

```py
#data_list = data_list = glob('dataset\\training\\*\\*.jpg')
dataset['train_img'] = _load_img()

def _load_img():
    data = [np.array(Image.open(v)) for v in data_list]
    a = np.array(data)
    a = a.reshape(-1, img_size * 3)

    return a

#normalize
for v in dataset:
   dataset['train_img'] = dataset['train_img'].astype(np.float32)
   dataset['train_img'] /= dataset['train_img'].max()
   dataset['train_img'] -= dataset['train_img'].mean(axis=1).reshape(len(dataset['train_img']), 1)
```

***EDIT***

I let the images to gray scale with `Image.open(v).convert('LA')`

and checking my prediction value, and it's example:

```
[-3.98576886e-04  3.41216374e-05] [1 0]
[ 0.00698861 -0.01111879] [1 0]
[-0.42003415  0.42222863] [0 1]
```

still not learning about the images. I removed 3 figures to test it, so I just have rectangle, and triangle total 252 images ( I drew more imges. )

And the prediction value is usually like opposite value( 3.1323, -3.1323  or 3.1323, -3.1303 ), I cannot figure out the reason.

Not just increasing numerical accuracy, when I use SGD for optimizer, the accuracy do not increase. Just same accuracy.

```
[ 0.02090227 -0.02085848] [1 0]
epoch:  0.5873015873015873
[ 0.03058879 -0.03086193] [0 1]
epoch:  0.5873015873015873
[ 0.04006064 -0.04004988] [1 0]
[ 0.04545139 -0.04547538] [1 0]
epoch:  0.5873015873015873
[ 0.05605123 -0.05595288] [0 1]
epoch:  0.5873015873015873
[ 0.06495255 -0.06500597] [1 0]
epoch:  0.5873015873015873
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Your model is performing pretty well. The problem is not related to normalization(not even a problem). The model actually predicted outside of 0,1 which means the model is really confident.

The model will not try to optimize towards [1,0,0,0] because when it calculates the loss, it will firstly clip the values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Loss is about to 70%, when I try to optimize the gradients of my model with SGD never decreasing about to 0.

And even I test it with new images for checking the accuracy is really about 95%, but it doesn't figure out the kinds of images' figure.

But maybe you are right. normalization is not the problem. Thanks.

Comment: You were right the model working fine. The problem was I had fewer images to learn. Thanks.